# MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.6 and Entity Framework 5 (and 6)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get EF 5 (and 6) to work with a MySQL server, but no matter what I do I seem to encounter strange errors. I am not sure what exactly is going on, I have been trying to get it to work for two days, but no luck. Generating the entity model from my database doesn't work, generating the database from a model doesn't work. Tried different version of the MySQL Connector/NET and it still doesn't work. Tried EF 5 and 6, and if I use EF 6 instead of 5, the dialog box just crashes.

I am beyond understanding how this even managed to get out of the alpha stage, or maybe I am simply doing something wrong? Something I am misunderstanding?

**UPDATE**

I Just uploaded a video to make it a little easier to see what it is I do when I try to make the entities.
http://youtu.be/eE9eRJtWw7E

[image: Generating db from model]
Generating db from model
[image: Generating db from model, error from SSDLToMySQL.tt]
Generating db from model, error from SSDLToMySQL.tt

-

[image: Generating model from db]
Generating model from db

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying with EF5 if it's a new project.  I would follow the instructions on the mysql website.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: Hey Coulton, I'll be looking into it, hopefully that will work. So far I have just added the ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: I'll probably try to create a youtube video so it's more clear what happens

Comment: What `MySql.Data.*` nuget version do you use? Make sure that it matches your connector version. Also, make sure to have the latest MySql Tools For VS installed. And, @Coulton is right, no reason to use EF 5.